# SQL Server: can reduce data file with partition table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I had database with one table called `Saler` stored at `C:\`, primary `.mdf` file is very big (100G and about 200 million rows) and my disc is nearly full

Now I add a new file group 'Secondary' and a new datafile stored at `D:\`. I partition this table share 100 million rows for primary (c:) and 100 million rows for secondary (D:) but I check the primary `.mdf` file is not reduced in size and the secondary file is upto 30G size.

Can reduce data file with partition table?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: What are your table, partition function, and partition scheme definitions? Is your data uniformly distributed over a range (say 1-200 mil)? Just doing the partitioning doesn't move data in a lot of cases.

Comment: I partition table Sale base on column Quarter (not is a primary key).  Quarter 1 and 2 on primary and other on secondary. My uniformly distributed over a range. After partition, I check 100mil stored on Primary and 100mil stored on Secondary, the secondary size is increase but the primary datafile is not reduce./.